# SQLalchemy couldn't find the target column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

```
ticker_table = Table('ticker_data', MetaData(),
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('ticker', String(100), nullable=False),
    Column('adj_slope', Float(3), nullable=False),
    Column('sector', String(100), nullable=False),
    Column('sub_sector', String(100), nullable=False)
    )
price_data = Table('price_data', MetaData(),
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('ticker', String(100), ForeignKey('ticker_data.ticker'), nullable=False),
    Column('date', Date),
    Column('price', Float(3)),
    )
price_data.create(bind=engine)
```

I'm getting this error

> Foreign key associated with column 'price_data.ticker' could not find table 'ticker_data' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'ticker'

I'm using MySQL Workbench with Python 3.6 and the most up to date everything else. Not sure what would be causing this error? Any help would be much appreciated. Maybe because I'm using the mysqlclient since the actual plugin isn't updated to python 3.6? I'm relatively new to all things sqlalchemy so any feedback would greatly benefit me.

Comment: Have you tried running `.create` on the ticker_data table prior to calling it on `price_data`?

Comment: Yes @jsbueno I just left the table outline for the ticker_table so people could see it how it was created.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using two fresh, unrelated  `MetaData` instances for each of your table. That way, inside sqlalchemy data structures, the second table won't "see" the other.

The correct thing to do is to use a single metadata object for both tables, and create both at once with a call to `.create_all()` on the MetaData instance:

```
...
metadata = MetaData()
ticker_table = Table('ticker_data', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('ticker', String(100), nullable=False),
    Column('adj_slope', Float(3), nullable=False),
    Column('sector', String(100), nullable=False),
    Column('sub_sector', String(100), nullable=False)
    )
price_data = Table('price_data', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('ticker', String(100), ForeignKey('ticker_data.ticker'), nullable=False),
    Column('date', Date),
    Column('price', Float(3)),
    )

metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

There is a way to ensure sqlalchemy "sees" the other table, even using distinct MetaData objects: just reference the foreign key column as the Python object, instead of a string. When you create a table, it gets the `c` attribute which is the column collection - so you could declare your second table like this:

```
price_data = Table('price_data', MetaData(),
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('ticker', String(100), ForeignKey(ticker_table.c.ticker), nullable=False),
    Column('date', Date),
    Column('price', Float(3)),
    )
```

Comment: I deleted the previous ticker_table from the db and did as you said with the .create_all() and the metadata variable and got this error. (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint') [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE price_data (\n\tid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, \n\tticker VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, \n\tdate DATE, \n\tprice FLOAT(3), \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(ticker) REFERENCES ticker_data (ticker)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

Comment: Mhm even with the ticker_table.c.ticker I'm still getting the same error 1215? Another stackoverflow page says the data types aren't the same. Yet the ticker is both set as String(100)...Not sure

Comment: Just googled up this: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/  - check reason 5 there: the referenced field should be indexed or a key!

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand by what an index or key exactly is? Like would I add an index=True under the column attributes? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the string `'ticker_data.ticker'` with the column name `ticker_table.c.ticker`, as in:

`Column('ticker', String(100), ForeignKey(ticker_table.c.ticker), nullable=False)`